# Alternative way of full outer join

Tags: sql, impala, hue

I am running this query

```
select * from
(select name, count(distinct id) as ids, date 
from table1
group by name, date ) as tt
full outer join
(select st_name as name,count(distinct id) as ids, date 
from table2  
group by st_name, date) as ts
on tt.name= ts.name
and tt.ids = ts.ids
```

It runs successfully but I want to ask if there is an alternative more efficient way to run this query.

Comment: What is the query trying to do? The code is very strange because it could be grabbing the number of ids from different dates and showing those as equal -- and that doesn't seem useful.

Comment: I am trying to find rows that do not exist in table1 or table2 after the matching of these 2 tables

Comment: @DrGenious . . . You probably want `date` in the `on` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to get days when the two numbers are not the same (it seems like the most reasonable thing you want from such a query).  So, this addresses that question.

`FULL OUTER JOIN` should be fine.  But an alternative is to try `UNION ALL` and aggregation:

```
select name, sum(ids_1), sum(ids_2), date
from ((select name, count(distinct id) as ids_1, NULL as ids_2, date 
       from table1
       group by name, date
      ) 
      union all
      (select st_name as name, NULL, count(distinct id) as ids_2, date 
       from table2  
       group by st_name, date
      )
     ) 
group by name, date
having sum(ids_1) = sum(ids_2)
```